# Get selected extension file count and size in a directory

Tags: shell, sh

How to print only `.TXT` or `.csv` files and their human-readable size in a folder

Example:

```
file type | total count | total size
.TXT        30            40MB
```

What I've done so far:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.TXT|csv" | wc -l
```

Answer (score 3):

That's going to be rough:

Find all files with the extensions, print the number of bytes and name for each file:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\.\(txt\|csv\)' -exec du -b {} \; |
```

Only keep the number of bytes and extension:

```
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\s+.*(\..*)/\1 \2/g' |
```

Calculate total count and size per extension using AWK (also call the `numfmt` command in the shell to make the thing human-readable) and format the table:

```
awk 'BEGIN{print "file type\ttotal count\ttotal size"} {totalSize[$2] += $1; count[$2]++} END {for (ext in count){ "numfmt --to=iec "totalSize[ext] | getline readableSize ;print ext"\t\t"count[ext]"\t\t"readableSize}}'
```

Full command:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\.\(txt\|csv\)' -exec du -b {} \; | 
sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\s+.*(\..*)/\1 \2/g' | 
awk 'BEGIN{print "file type\ttotal count\ttotal size"} {totalSize[$2] += $1; count[$2]++} END {for (ext in count){ "numfmt --to=iec "totalSize[ext] | getline readableSize ;print ext"\t\t"count[ext]"\t\t"readableSize}}'
```

Output looks like this, it's easy to be standardized if you fiddle with that awk printing:

```
file type   total count total size
gradle      109         89K
txt         2283        680M
```

That being said I feel dirty just seeing it. That's well beyond the point where python would be more readable.

Comment: i tried to run the command in a .sh file and i got the bad option regex error. How do i resolve this?

Comment: @TesCix - what is the version of your find (`find --version`)? This was tested on GNU find 4.7.0

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to do cumulative sizes + file counts in a single command, but you can use the following, assign them to variables and then print out the results with whatever tabular format you want.

Cumulative file size with multiple extensions:

```
find . -type f -regex '.*\.\(txt\|csv\)' -exec du -ch {} + | grep total$ | cut -f1
```

Cumulative file size with a single extension:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec du -ch {} + | grep total$ | cut -f1
```

File count with multiple extensions:

```
find -regex '.*\.\(txt\|csv\)' | wc -l
```

File count with a single extension:

```
find . -type f -name "*.txt" | wc -l
```

Comment: Add `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 ` before command if you're using non-English locale